# how to make when selecting items from 2 comboboxes dyanamically link to 3 rd combobox in java swings netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I am creating two comboboxes and inserting some elements like suzuki,Honda,activa into first combo and Renault,Indica,Benz into second combo box, and also i am creating  3rd combo which has nothing to insert. my question is  when I will select an item in first for example if I select suzuki in first combo and Renault in second, both of these suzuki and Renault should appear in 3rd combobox, and if I change activa in first and Indica in second then 3rd combo should display activa and Indica. like this 3rd combo box should dyanamically get the selected items from first and second.

Plz help me,
Thanks and Regards,
-Chandrashekara Y D.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) and register it at the first two ComboBox instances by calling [`addActionListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29).

In your action listener, update the model of the third ComboBox. Initially set a [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html). In the action listener call [getModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getModel%28%29) and add/remove whatever you want. Or just create a new DefaultComboBoxModel every time and set it.

Comment: can you have any example programs?

Comment: Try yourself and show what you have, if you need help. (Or pay someone to do the work.)

Answer (score 0):

But should 3rd combo box remember values from first choice?
For example you have choosen suzuki in 1st, renault in 2nd, there are suzuki and renault in 3rd.
Now you change selection of 1st to activa and 2nd to indica. Should 3rd one be cleared and now contain activa and indica only? Or all 4 values (suzuki, renault, avtiva, indica)?

I guess 1st and 2nd combo are binded, and value to the 3rd should be added ONLY, when position in 1st AND 2nd combo are selected?

Easiest way is to create a button with handler, so where you click it, it will take data from 1st and 2nd combo and add it to 3rd (cleared or not).

If you want to operate only on selections, this one would be more complex. I guess you should introduce variables (boolean) to hold current state of each combo box. So you change boolean state of each boolean (cb1, cb2) to `true` when selected. In each cb selection handler you check if both boolean values are true, add proper values to 3rd cb and set boolean values back to `false`.

Not sure if it solves your problem, there are many possible scenarios to cover. I would stand for button - simple and more straightforward.

Comment: But should 3rd combo box remember values from first choice? For example you have choosen suzuki in 1st, renault in 2nd, there are suzuki and renault in 3rd. Now you change selection of 1st to activa and 2nd to indica. Should 3rd one be cleared and now contain activa and indica only,,,,,as you said this is my requirement..

Comment: Is I have to write the code 3rd combobox's ActionPerformed or else I have call a method from ActonPerformed.